How to resolve "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"
This is a nextjs project with jest for testing. I added the next-auth library and my tests are now failing when the test suite is running for the file that imports import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
This is the error message:
Details:

/node_modules/next-auth/react.js:10
import { jsx as _jsx } from "react/jsx-runtime";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module



  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/shared/components/header.tsx:1767:27)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/shared/components/header.test.tsx:22:56)

I'm assuming this is a jest.config.js issue, I have it configured like this:
import nextJest from 'next/jest';
import type { Config } from 'jest';

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: './',
});

const config: Config = {
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.ts', 'src/**/*.tsx'],
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules',
    'qsrkit',
    '_redux',
    'shared/utils',
    'layout',
    'page.tsx',
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'json', 'node'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^@/app/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/app/$1',
    '^@/shared/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/shared/$1',
    '^@/icons/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/shared/assets/icons/$1',
    '^@/utils/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/shared/utils/$1',
  },
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  reporters: ['default', 'jest-junit'],
  roots: ['<rootDir>'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/playwright/'],
  watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/playwright/'],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/playwright/'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
};

export default createJestConfig(config);

I thought since I'm already ignoring /node_modules/ this wouldn't get caught but clearly that isn't working.

Jest use CommonJS environment by default, so import statements are not allowed. Use require instead. It’s like a reminder:)
When working with tests it’s a best practice to mock any external libraries. As for next/auth package, try to mock it
// mock/next-auth.js
module.exports = {
  signIn: jest.fn(),
  signOut: jest.fn(),
  useSession: jest.fn(() => ({ data: null, status: "unauthenticated" })),
};


